# Using settings object with brackets [] accessor on product page

Tags: shopify

There seems to be some magic happening here for `{{ settings[a_prop] }}` on a product page. It seems that `{{ settings[a_prop] }}` is equivalent to the property `a_prop_productname` in my `settings.html` (instead of `a_prop`, which makes more sense to me). This is all happening in my theme's `product.liquid`.

Can anyone explain where `productname` is getting pulled from? Also, normally liquid uses dot notation for `settings`... why do brackets work here? I can't find any examples anywhere on the internet.

Comment: I've edited the question (pending review, it should be visible in a few mins). Let me know if I've missed anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/basics/handle#handles-created

Shopify will automatically create handle based on the product/page/whatever title you provide.

https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/basics/handle#attributes-handle

You can do both `{{ obj[attr] }}` or `{{ obj.attr }}` to access an object attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`{{ obj[attr] }}` means "access the property on obj with the value of the variable attr" and `{{ obj.attr }}` means "access the property attr on obj".